# db_select with subquery including conditions from 2 tables

Tags: database

I spent much time without success to search how to convert with db_select the following query, running perfectly with db_query :

```
    SELECT *
    FROM job_orders j
    WHERE j.statut = 'To do'
    AND j.job
    IN ( SELECT r.job
    FROM referential r
    WHERE r.category = j.category
    AND r.label = :label
    AND r.activity = :activity ),
    array(':label' => $label, ':activity' => $activity);
```

Here is the corresponding (?) db_select query I wrote :

```
$subquery = db_select('referential', 'r')
    ->fields('r', array('job'))
    ->condition('r.category', 'j.category')
    ->condition('r.label', $label)
    ->condition('r.activity', $activity);

$query = db_select('job_orders', 'j')
    ->fields('j')
    ->condition('j.statut', 'To do')
    ->condition('j.job', $subquery, 'IN');
$results = $query->execute();
```

I got no result with this db_select query, while I got answers with the db_query one... could somebody tell me what is wrong in my db_select query ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired behavior you have two options.

If you really like to filter by using a subquery, you should execute it first, parse its result set to an array and set this array as parameter to the condition method of your second queries db_select:

```
// Run your subquery first.
$subquery = db_select('referential', 'r')
  ->fields('r', array('job'))
  ->condition('r.category', 'j.category')
  ->condition('r.label', $label)
  ->condition('r.activity', $activity);
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('job');

// Make sure $results is initialized for further evaluation.
$results = array();

// If we have referential results, execute the query on job orders.
if (!empty($result)) {
  $query = db_select('job_orders', 'j')
    ->fields('j')
    ->condition('j.statut', 'To do')
    ->condition('j.job', array_keys($result), 'IN');
  $results = $query->execute();
}
```

The far more elegant and therefore suggested solution is to using an [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on your query. The target query would look like:

```
SELECT j.*
  FROM job_orders j
  INNER JOIN referential r ON (r.job = j.job)
  WHERE j.statut = 'To do' AND r.label = :label AND r.activity = :activity
```

You can achieve this solution using db_select by adding a [join](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7) to your $query:

```
  // Run the query using an INNER JOIN.
  $query = db_select('job_orders', 'j')
    ->join('referential', 'r', 'r.job = j.job');
  $query->fields('j')
    ->condition('j.statut', 'To do')
    ->condition('r.label', $label)
    ->condition('r.activity', $activity);
  $results = $query->execute();
```

**Edit:**
As I don't see any special reason for using db_select in your use case, I'd also suggest on sticking to db_query here for better performance of your application.

**Edit 2:**
In the above 'solutions' I have overseen you are using two conditions between the tables. In this case, you have to add both conditions to your JOIN:

```
SELECT j.*
  FROM job_orders j
  INNER JOIN referential r ON (r.job = j.job AND r.category = j.category)
  WHERE j.statut = 'To do' AND r.label = :label AND r.activity = :activity
```

Which would need the following db_select:

```
  $query = db_select('job_orders', 'j')
    ->join('referential', 'r', 'r.job = j.job AND r.category = j.category');
  $query->fields('j')
    ->condition('j.statut', 'To do')
    ->condition('r.label', $label)
    ->condition('r.activity', $activity);
  $results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'd want to use `db_select` because I need a pager to display results, and extend `PagerDefault` doesn't work with `db_query`. I've tried your 2 solutions, but still no success :( - the first one can't work because of `"condition('r.category', 'j.category')"` : `"j"` alias isn't yet associated with the corresponding table
- the second one return no results too But it gave me an idea : I tried to run `db_select` queries without `"condition('r.category', 'j.category')"`, and it return results ! but too much of course, the condition is needed. Here is a summary of wh

Comment: Altered my above answer. (Edit 2)

Comment: "Mais c'est bien sûr !" as we say in France :)
Thank you very very much Mario, it's working like a charm !

Comment: Sorry bummi and kiamlaluno, I'm new on the forum and I didn't know. I'll remember that !